# 4-syllable (X-Y-X-Z) slang phrases

Tags: slang

What do you call phrases that are in the pattern of X-Y-X-Z such as *Maddaog Mattis*, "*man crush Monday*" and *Throw-back Thursday*?

Comment: Are you asking for [alliteration](https://www.google.com/search?q=alliteration+definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NcvaWI2UFcXI8AfviYeYDA)?

Comment: Maybe you’re thinking of a two-foot trochaic expression?